# Is it possible to watch Netflix with 4K quality on Manjaro?

Tags: manjaro, linux-tv

I have 2K(2560x1440 16:9) monitor, i have Firefox extension (Netflix 1080p) for the name of science and for my interest i want to watch Netflix in 4K, please tell me is it possible to watch Netflix with 4K quality ?
And how this service checks our devices for 4K supporting and we able to imitate what our device supports 4K ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Netflix is available in Ultra HD on Windows and Mac computers with:
>
> - Microsoft Edge for Windows
> - Windows 10 App
> - Safari for MacOS 11.0 or later
>
> These computers require a 60Hz monitor to play Ultra HD content.

https://help.netflix.com/en/node/13444